# Sorting program using socket programming in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to implement any one sorting algorithm using TCP/UDP on Server application and Give Input On Client side and client should sorted output from server and display sorted on input side. Here, I have created program for multiplication of a number. I am not getting how to pass int array from client side and receive the same array. How can I do that.It would be a great help. Thank in advance.

```
Client.java 

package sorting_app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client
{

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25000;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            String number = "2";

            String sendMessage = number + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Server.java 

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{

    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            int port = 25000;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");

            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true)
            {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String number = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);

                //Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
                String returnMessage;
                try
                {
                    int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                    int returnValue = numberInIntFormat*2;
                    returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                    returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                }

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                bw.write(returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
                bw.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` are for character streams.

Consider using other ways, like [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

(DataOutputStream / DataInputStream could be good too)

Comment: Can you do the code for dataoutput stream.because it is not working

Comment: You have an example in this topic for Data Streams as well as Object Streams : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984142/how-to-write-array-to-outputstream-in-java