# How can I write a short array to a DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, android

Currently I am writing an array of shorts to a DataOutputStream as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
{
   dos.writeShort(audioBuffer[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to do it one swoop as opposed per each element?

Thanks

Comment: As per Javadocs `A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data types to an output stream` - An array is not a primitive

Comment: So maybe use an ObjectOutputStream if applicable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write array to outputStream in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984142/how-to-write-array-to-outputstream-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As @Scary Wombat suggested, according to [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

> An object is a class instance or an array.

DataOutputStream is for primitive type but not object.

You can use `ObjectOutputStream` to write array to outputstream at one swoop.

For example,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            try{
                short audioBuffer[] = new short[10000];
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt")));
                oos.writeObject(audioBuffer);
                oos.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work if you are trying to write to a certain format, like an image, or a sound track.